# Letterpress effect with CSS

Tags: css

I want to make a letterpress effect like this: 
[image: http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/6421/letterpress.png]
 in CSS. but I can't seem to find the right text-shadow for it.

Color of the word: #2f4050
Color of the background: #4f6478

i've tried it with:

```
.letterpress {
    color:#2f4050;
    font-family:Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:70px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:normal;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:#4f6478 0 1px 5px; 
}
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: The image you've linked to is broken, for me at least.

Comment: Yes the image is broken.

Comment: http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/6421/letterpress.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.letterpress {
    color:#2f4050;
    font-family:Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:70px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff; 
}
```

That should do it. Btw. you don't have to declare the "normal" value pairs

Answer (score 5):

There are two shadows. Try something like

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), -1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

This should give a transparent white shadow to the bottom right and a transparent black *inner* shadow to the top left.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lighter color for the shadow, and less blur. Something like:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #6ab;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text shadow is the same colour as the background. You should use a lighter colour like `#809bb5`. Or you can use an rgba value for example `text-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);`. The last number is alpha transparency (opacity).

I tweaked the shadow slightly... http://jsfiddle.net/qmqF5/

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is simple.

You are giving same color for background-color and text shadow.

Giving lighter color to text shadow compared to background and the text color solves the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To create the letterpress effect, we need to add a shadow that’s lighter than the colour of the text to ensure the effect works correctly.