# How To Center a Letterpress Effect?

Tags: css

Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qkAJD/

### HTML

```
<div style="width:500px;">
     <h1 class="success-header" title="Success!">Success!</h1>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    background: gray;
    margin:0;
}
.success-header {
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}
.success-header:before {
    content: attr(title);
    position:absolute;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
}
```

### Result

[image]

### Question

How can we center the `<h1>` tag within its container, and still keep the letterpress effect?  Assume that we don't know in advance that the container's width is 500px.  That is, a solution which hardcodes the position of the header is not acceptable.  It's easy enough to center the header:

```
<div style="width:500px;text-align:center">
     <h1 class="success-header" title="Success!">Success!</h1>
</div>
```

But this destroy's the letterpress effect:

[image]

Comment: Why this method over text-shadow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830703/letterpress-effect-with-css

Comment: You mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/qkAJD/5/

Comment: @kunalbhat, I have never been able to get the text shadow method to look like a good letterpress.  for example: http://jsfiddle.net/alicemunro/rDdDg/ is just not really a letterpress.  if i'm doing it wrong, and you can make it look similar to my solution using only text shadow, please put an answer up with that and I'll upvote you, even though it's technically not an answer to the OP

Comment: Sure, I did put an answer to the OP, first mind you :), but no one upvoted :) It's a shark tank out here!

Comment: There, I upvoted you. BTW, I didn't steal your answer (note that my fiddle comment was posted a minute before your answer).

Comment: Hah @TimMedora, no worries, didn't see that while I was writing :). Right back atchya.

Comment: @kunalbhat, Ah, I think I got it, just need to use a negative value: http://jsfiddle.net/rDdDg/1/

Comment: You're right, its pretty tough... not as strong. I'm no sandwich artist though: http://jsfiddle.net/qkAJD/8/

Comment: Eh, I take it back.  It's really not as good when I tried it in my actual application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "shadow" is positioned absolutely with relation to its nearest eligible parent. You can make the immediate parent eligible by adding `position:relative` to it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qkAJD/5/

```
.success-header {
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative; /* changed line */
}
```

> Absolute - Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at
>   a specified position relative to its **closest positioned ancestor or
>   to the containing block**.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), emphasis mine.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `positon: relative` to `.success-header`, since you already are positioning the shadow absolutely.

```
.success-header {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/LRtjx/1/)